# Clang gives me a warning of signedness change, however the code still produces correct output

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-warnings, implicit-conversion, unsigned-integer

I was analyzing some warnings in a codebase and got puzzled by this one generated by Clang

Consider the following C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int , char *[])
{

  uint32_t val1 = 10;
  int32_t val2 = -20;

  int32_t result = val1 + val2;
  std::cout << "Result is " << result << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Clang gives me the following warning when compiling this code with `-Wconversion`

```
<source>:9:25: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 
'unsigned int' to 'int32_t' (aka 'int') [-Wsign-conversion]

  int32_t result = val1 + val2;

          ~~~~~~   ~~~~~^~~~~~
<source>:9:27: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 
'int32_t' (aka 'int') to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]

  int32_t result = val1 + val2;

                        ~ ^~~~
2 warnings generated.
```

GCC also gives me this warning, however I need to provide `-Wsign-conversion` to trigger it.

The warning says that `val2` will be cast to an `unsigned int` and therefore will loose it's sign. So far so good. However I was expecting that the code above would produce *incorrect* output, to my surprise it works perfectly fine.

```
Result is -10
```

See the program running on both compilers [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6nXPxC).

The cast does not happen in the compiled code and `val2` keep its original value. The result of the computation is correct. What is the *actual* danger that this warning is warning me against? How can I trigger this behaviour? Is the warning bogus?

Comment: If you imagine (e.g.) bounds checking for an array access, you need to be extremely careful about signed <-> unsigned conversions to avoid a security hole. This is (very) far from hypothetical. So being explicit about such conversions is arguably good style, even if the result is what you expect on every machine you will ever encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the actual danger that this warning is warning me against?

The potential danger is that you may have been unaware of the implicit sign conversion, and have made it by accident. If it is intentional and behaves as desired, then there is no danger).

> How can I trigger this behaviour?

You already have triggered an implicit sign conversion.

That said, if you want to see some output which may be surprising to you, try this instead:

```
std::cout << val1 + val2;
```

> Is the warning bogus?

Depends on your definition of bogus.

There definitely is an implicit sign conversion in the program, and therefore if you ask the compiler to warn about implicit sign conversions, then it is entirely correct for the compiler to warn about the implicit sign conversion that is in the program.

There is a reason why this warning option is not enabled by default, nor when enabling "all" warnings using `-Wall`, nor even when enabling "extra" warnings with `-Wextra`. These sign conversion warnings warn about a program with well defined behaviour, but which may be surprising to someone who is not paying close attention. A program can be meaningful and correct despite this warning.

Comment: Both of the answers are good and I have upvoted both. I chose yours because you provided code to trigger the unwanted behavior.

Comment: My interpretation is that the casting of `val2` screws up the value but the casting back to `result` fixes the problem. So it works by accident. https://godbolt.org/z/3DbYC4

Comment: I agree, this answer has the advantage of illustrating how things can go really bad if you ignore these warnings. For reference, it prints `429496728618446744073709551616` on my machine (64-bit Linux).

Answer (score 3):

The *second* conversion is where things become implementation dependent.

The first (evaluation of expression `val1+val2`) triggers conversion of `val2` to unsigned from signed, which is standard-compliant and documented. The result of the expression is therefore unsigned.

The second (conversion of the resulting unsigned *back* to signed) is where potential problems ensue. If the unsigned value is not within the defined domain of the target signed type (and in this case, it isn't), implementation behavior ensues, which you cannot assume is portable across the known universe.

Comment: While initialisation of signed integer with a value outside of representable range is technically implementation defined, `int32_t` is guaranteed to have two's complement representation, so there is really only one value that could reasonably be expected. Portability to non-two's complement systems had already been lost by using `int32_t`. Since C++20, this result is guaranteed with no exceptions.